# FMDatabase.h not found when using route-me library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fmdb, route-me

So im trying to use the route-me widget in my app, but xcode keeps complaining that it cant find FMDatabase.h, yet its included in the project (albeit under a different project that is included into my project). I've copied how a sample app has been made yet the sample project doesnt get this error. The RMDBMapSource.h file is contained within the MapView project, so i shouldn't need to include the fmdb stuff myself (and because the sample project doesn't do that)

[image]

[image]

Surely if the files are under compile sources / copy headers under build phases, that means it should be able to find the file?  This is a pretty lackluster explanation of my problem, but if anyone has used the route-me library before maybe they have had the same problem and can point me in the right direction

Comment: Check if it's being imported like `#import "FMDatabase.h"`, and if it is you can try `#import <FMDatabase.h>`...

Comment: i just tried that, didnt work. i shouldnt need to change that anyway since its all bundled up in this MapView project so i dont think its a case of the code being wrong, just xcode being silly

Comment: You've shown in the .h in the Build Sources. Is the .m there too? You don't need the .h files there. You need the .m files.

Comment: yeah the .m is there, i think ive solved half of it though, the FMDatabase.h not found error is gone.. but now im getting a linker error `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in InfoTableHelper.o` which is odd because im referencing RMMapView from a different file as well and that doesnt give a linker error. (tried only having it referenced in one file at a time and it only gives error for the infoTableHelper)

Comment: ok what i said is semi-false, it has the linker error where ever i do a `[RMMapView alloc]init]` which is odd.. if i have `RMMapView *map = [array objectAtIndex:0]` then its fine with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my own mistake. First off in the build settings of the main project, the 'search for header paths' was not set correctly, it was set to `/MapView/` instead of `/MapView/**` that resolved the FMDatabase.h missing error.

Then in case someone else had a linker error like i did after i resolved the first issue, make sure you have `libMapView.a` included in your link binary with libraries section. (i had it their before, but during a version control commit, somehow our project file decided to not add that library anymore and i had totally forgotten about it, so took me quite a while to find out that it was missing)