# Bridging Header: file not found (using Objective C into Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I'm trying to integrate the [UniPay iOS SDK with my iOS app.](https://atlassian.idtechproducts.com/confluence/display/KB/UniPay+1.5+(IDMR-xB83133-xx)+-+Home) I've imported the required IDTech.framework as instructed, added the Bridging Header File (set the Swift Compiler Build Settings to it already). I am now trying to import the needed IDTech.h header file in the Bridging Header with:

```
#ifndef Swift_Bridging_Header_h
#define Swift_Bridging_Header_h

#import <IDTech/IDTech.h>

#endif
```

however I get 2 issues from XCode 9.3.1:
-Swift Compiler Error:

'IDTech/IDTech.h' file not found (CardSwipe-Bridging-Header.h)
and

Failed to emit precompiled header '/User/..../Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/.....pch' fir bridging header

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49762579/1009546

Comment: Did you try deep Clean( Option-Shift-Command-K ) and rebuild the project?

Comment: @ericl I tried the deep clean, still running into same issue

Comment: @battlmonstr I looked at it, I tried the adjusting of the User Header Search Paths and no dice. I'm getting the same 2 errors.

Comment: Don't use "User Header Search Paths", use "Header Search Paths", because you import with angle brackets.

Comment: @battlmonstr I tried adding $(PROJ_DIR)/IDTech (the framework is in a folder named iDTech in the main project folder. Also tried $(PROJ_DIR)/IDTech/**, $(SRCROOT)/IDTech, $(SRCROOT)/IDTech/**, $(SRCROOT)/**, $(SRCROOT) both recurse and non-recursive (each) in the Header Search Paths and I'm getting the same error:
'IDTech/IDTech.h' file not found Cardswipe-Bridging-Header.h 
&

Failed to emit precompiled header '/.../../

Comment: If you have `IDTech.h` file at `$HOME/Desktop/MyProject/IDTech/IDTech.h`, and your xcodeproj is at `$HOME/Desktop/MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj`, then normally you need to add `$(SRCROOT)` to the search paths. ( because `$SRCROOT = $HOME/Desktop/MyProject`). Things like `/**` are not supported there.

Comment: @battlmonstr Yes, I tried it all ways, same issue.

Comment: Please write the full path to IDTech.h on your file system, the full project folder path, and the exact Header Search Path that you try to add, then I can help.